# Direct mapping cache with LRU

Tags: cpu-cache

I'm studying computer architecture and I'm doing an experiment.
Does LRU make sense in a direct mapping cache? I'm quite confused.
Thank you.

Comment: In a direct-mapped cache, each address only has one choice for placement, so the least recently used block is the only block (and LRU is equivalent to random, FIFO, etc.). (Side thought: One could use information about block access time to allocate, when the present block has been accessed recently, an incoming block to an assist cache — a small more associative cache accessed  (unlike a victim cache) in parallel with L1. This would avoid some thrashing compared to randomly allocating to the assist cache or the main cache.)

Answer (score 3):

LRU only applies if the cache is set-associative and you need a hint as to in which set you write new data.  In a direct mapped cache, here is only one place to put data.